# Registering PHP echo from webview

Tags: php, android, webview

I need to access the authentification service of my school in order to authenticate clients on my app. The authentification service, at this time, only allows registration via browsers.

I set up a webview which properly accesses the authentification page, but I have 2 questions:

1. I access a PHP script that returns my username as a String echo. How can I register that string into Android?
2. How can I close the webview once I've run the script? It only should run for authentification.

Answer (score 0):

With a little peaking under the hood of how HTTP requests are built, you should be able to do this without a WebView, and instead just build your own interface to collect the username/password/etc and then build your own HTTP requests. Then your challenge is simply parsing the returned body from the requests, which *hopefully* support getting JSON as a response Content-Type to make your life easier.